# Swift: Protocol conformance - Is this a bug or not?

Tags: swift

(On XCode 6 beta 3)

This code raises an error "Type MyClass does not conform to protocol MyProtocol".

```
class A {}
class B : A {}

protocol PPP {
    func foobar(x: B)
}
class MyClass : PPP {  // --> error: doesn't conform to PPP
    func foobar(x: A) {}
}
```

However, the code below is OK:

```
class MyClass : PPP {
    func foobar(x: B) {}
}
class MySubClass : MyClass {
    override func foobar(x: A) {}
}
var p:PPP = MySubClass()
```

When I explicitly apply PPP on MySubClass, the same error is raised again:

```
class MyClass : PPP {
    func foobar(x: B) {}
}
class MySubClass : MyClass, PPP {  // --> error: doesn't conform to PPP
    override func foobar(x: A) {}
}
```

I'm not sure this behaviour is a bug or not. Do you think?

Comment: Are you using beta 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm using XCode 6 beta 3.

Comment: FYI, asked about beta version because I though it was a protocol problem I found last week, occurring when a protocol indirectly inherits another protocol multiple times - which has been fixed in beta 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the 1st code is that the method in the `PPP` protocol:

```
func foobar(x: B)
```

expects to receive an instance of `B`. You are overriding specifying a parameter of type `A`, which is different than `B`, even if it's a superclass. In order to confirm to the protocol, you have to implement a method exactly as declared in the protocol. I don't think it's a bug.

More interestingly, in the last case:

```
class MyClass : PPP {
    func foobar(x: B) { print ("BaseB")}
}

class MySubClass : MyClass, PPP {
    override func foobar(x: B) { print("B") }
}

var xx = MySubClass()

xx.foobar(B())
```

outputs `B`, which is what I'd expect. Instead:

```
class MyClass : PPP {
    func foobar(x: B) { print ("BaseB")}
}

class MySubClass : MyClass, PPP {
    override func foobar(x: A) { print("A") }
    override func foobar(x: B) { print("B") }
}

var xx = MySubClass()

xx.foobar(A())
xx.foobar(B())
```

outputs `AA`, whereas I'd expect `AB`. That smells like a bug.

Comment: OK. I understand that the `override` does consider type inheritance while the protocol does not. This inconsistency causes this problem.

Comment: It seems to take the first method it finds that works. Probably a bug, potentially just poor design

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug. In your first example your class does not fully implement all of the methods in PPP. `foobar(x: B)` is different from `func foobar(x: A)` even though you could pass a B into `func foobar(x: B)`  Add `func foobar(x: B) {}` to `MyClass` and it should work.

Comment: `func foobar(x: A)` is not the same function as `func foobar(x: B)` and it should call the right one depending on the type of the value passed in. It seems like the "B" version should be inherited and the "A" version should be added in the subclass (i.e., I think it *is* a bug – the third example, not the first one)

Comment: I can't try it right now, but it would be interesting to see what it calls when the argument has been explicitly typed. It may have something to do with swift's implicit typing.

Comment: I thought the same, and did that test (see my answer). Passing `A` and `B`, the method accepting `A` is always invoked, which is what I don't expect.

Comment: @Jiaaro: "I think it is a bug – the third example, not the first one" Why do you think it is a bug in the third one if not the first one? If in the first example, `MyClass` does not conform to `PPP` because its `foobar` takes an `A`, then in the third example, `MySubClass` should equally not conform to `PPP`, for the exact same reason, `foobar` takes `A`.